# Making a new sheet with only the highlighted cells in the mother sheet - Python/Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a mother workbook, view here (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13UnBY3umkojHMd9K9PYv8zITu253vO_ipHNxLvE5u9Q/edit#gid=521061986), of which I have only kept sheets 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'. I have copied this spreadsheet to my drive and I am highlighting the events I am interested in (changing the fill color to yellow). I want to create a code that creates a new 'schedule' based on the events that I highlighted... Keeping the yellow events but setting the other events to null and deleting empty rows.

So far, I've successfully connected to my db, but I don't know how to identify the cells by their fill color.

```py
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


DATA_DIR = '/path/here/'
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
path = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'client_secret.json')
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)


spreadsheet = client.open('dcon').sheet1

sheets = ['Saturday', 'Sunday']
# deleted every other sheet except Saturday & Sunday since that's when I'll be there


def get_sheet_colors(spreadsheet, ranges: list):
    params = {'ranges': ranges,
              'fields': 'sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat/backgroundColor,formattedValue)),'
                        'startColumn,startRow),properties(sheetId,title))'}
    return spreadsheet.get(**params).execute()

desiredA1NotationRanges = ['Sunday''!A1:K2', 'Saturday''!B2:D4']
# these are example ranges
get_sheet_colors(spreadsheet, desiredA1NotationRanges)
```

I tried this function that I pulled from another StackOverflow question, but I can't run 'get' on a 'worksheet' object. Does anyone have any ideas for this, or maybe there's an easier way to identify events I'm interested in so the code is easier to write?

Comment: Can I ask you about the input situation and output situation you want?

Comment: @Tanaike sure! The mother df is a mess with info, making it really hard to navigate. I have highlighted certain events (cells) that I'm interested in on the copied version on my Drive, but I don't want the rest of the events there. Basically I want to create my own schedule here, where the only values in the df are the ones that I've highlighted, leaving the rest of the df with only holes. For rows that contain only holes (no highlights), I want them deleted. But I want to keep all the columns to keep the time consistent, regardless of whether I've highlighted anything in that time frame.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't image the vision of your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this situation. But I think that other users will be able to understand about your replying.

Comment: I have tried to understand about your question. Unfortunately, I cannot still do it. I apologize for this.